# migrate previous magento into new magento

Tags: magento2

Hi i want to know how to migrate previous magento customers details with purchases into new magento 2.1 store.
I have tried to look into the database, but was not able to find the required details.
Actually I have re-designed my website, the older website is in Magento 1.9 and I want to migrate all the previous registered users, their details and their purchase history into my new website developed on magento 2.1
Kindly advice how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides migration tools to migrate useful data from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x.

Please have a look [here](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool).

For more details, visit [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html).